# Rails validates :username, exclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  validates :username, exclusion: { in: %w(about account root etc..)
```

I am using the above to disallow users from using reserved usernames but they are still able to use them between underscores (I do allow underscores in usernames)

Is there anyway I can make rails validate the reserved username even if it is before or after an underscore?

Thanks

Comment: If you are strictly about "if it is before or after an underscore", you could use that validation, but use a function to generate all the possibilities. Ie, exclusion: { in : %w(about account root).map {|name|[name,"_#{name}","#{name}_"]}.compact }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a method to do your validations for you and use plain old ruby in that. As you can see [in the docs here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

This would look something like this for you:

```
  validate :my_validation_method

  def my_validation_method
    errors.add(:username, :exclusion) if some_condition
  end
```

What this does is say that the model needs to be validated with the `my_validation_method` as well as all your normal other validations. You then manually add the field that is in error (in your case :username) to the errors of the model, thus it fails validation.

Also note the `validate` rather than `validates`.

Your other question is basically how to check whether an entered value includes some words. You could do this like so:

```
def my_validation_method
   forbid = %w(luke darth artoo fry bender)

   errors.add(:username, :exclusion) if forbid.find { |w| username.include?(w) }
end
```

Here I added a condition to the adding of the error where we loop through each word in the forbidden list and check if username includes this word. Note that "blablaluke" would fail too! So it is not completely what you'd want. But you can play around with this yourself of course.

The level of normalization you do (e.g. stripping away other characters) could give you more control, like preventing `ad_min`, etc.

Update:
You can strip away characters like so:

```
username.tr('-_+$^&', '')
```

You can add whatever you want to strip away to that first string in `tr`.

Comment: oh no, faster and better answer. d'oh!

Comment: Thank you very much, but how would I strip away other characters in your above example? so users cannot do something like ad_min

Comment: @ukeagle I expanded my answer a little for you.

Comment: errors.add(:username, :exclusion) if forbid.find { |w| username.tr("_","").include?(w) }

Comment: @ukeagle yep something like that.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [rails docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion) this way you can only check if a value is in a set of given values.

> This helper validates that the attributes' values are not included in a given set.

i would just write a custom validation [method](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) - you can do whatever you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a Regex. Like this one:

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A(([ _]*)(?!(about|admin|root|etc)[ _])[^ _]+)+([ _]+|\z)\z/
```

Comment: lol, then I'd write that same custom validator that @mosselman suggested. The only caveat - seems like something someone might have written a gem for. I'd search for that.